# My column has text in the form of year and month, I want to display it as a decimal number

Tags: powerbi

[Column image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9yun.png)

I have a column that has data in the form mentioned above, I want to show this data as a decimal number. For example, if the cell value is 1y 6m, I want to display it as 1 + (6/12) = 1.5

I am new to Power BI and I am looking for ways with which I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this M-code and put it into the PowerQuery Advanced Editor.
The steps are:

1. Split column by delimiter " "
2. Extract text before "y" and convert it to number
3. Extract text before "m" and convert it to number
4. Add custom column with YearMonthDecimal = [Year] + [Month] /12

```
let
    Source = Table.FromValue("1y 6m"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(
        Source, "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Year", "Month"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Year", type text}, {"Month", type text}}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(
        #"Changed Type", {{"Year", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "y"), type text}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter",{{"Year", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1" = Table.TransformColumns(
        #"Changed Type1", {{"Month", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "m"), type text}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1",{{"Month", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Changed Type2", "YearMonthDecimal", each [Year] + [Month] /12),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Added Custom",{{"YearMonthDecimal", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type3"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a **new column** as below-

```
Column = 

var y_index = Find("y", TRIM(your_table_name[Column1]),1,0)-1
var m_index = Find("m", TRIM(your_table_name[Column1]),1,0)

var year_value = 
if(
    ISBLANK(your_table_name[Column1]) || your_table_name[Column1] = "",
    BLANK(),
    LEFT(TRIM(your_table_name[Column1]),y_index)
)

var month_value_temp = 
if(
    ISBLANK(your_table_name[Column1]) || your_table_name[Column1] = "",
    BLANK(),
    RIGHT(TRIM(your_table_name[Column1]),m_index - y_index -2)
)

var m_index_new = Find("m", TRIM(month_value_temp),1,0) - 1

var month_value = 
if(
    ISBLANK(your_table_name[Column1]) || your_table_name[Column1] = "",
    BLANK(),
    LEFT(month_value_temp,m_index_new)
)

RETURN year_value + (month_value/12)
```

Here is the output-

[image]